# How do I join more than one files, in a Linq (C#) where one of the joins is a left join

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

My Sql below works great, but now I would like to join another file that has a common key. The file I would like to join has could have one to many records, any suggestions

here is my code:

```
 var regPoints = (from x in db.CertPoints
                                 join y in db.CommunityPts on x.PointId equals y.PointId into z
                                 from t in
                                     (from r in z
                                      where r.CommunityId == id select r).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 where x.TypeId == 1 
                                 select new Points
                                 {
                                     pointId = x.PointId,
                                     pointsDescription = x.PointDescription,
                                     points = x.Points,
                                     dateApplied = t.DateApplied,
                                     pointsEarned = t.PointsEarned,
                                     pointsPending = t.Pending ? true : false,
                                     pointsApproved = t.Approved ? true : false,
                                     notes = t.Notes

                                 }).AsEnumerable();
```

the new join would be a one to many records, where the key in CommunityPts is Id, and the file I would like to join is a list of file links "CommunityPtsDocs" with a foreign key CommnunityPtId. How do i add it to the above sql statement above?

Comment: Maybe you should first think of adding navigation properties so you don't need these joins in your LINQ (it's not SQL).

Comment: Thank you ... I am trying a different approach

Comment: A simple Join under the initial join between `CertPoints` and `CommunityPts` shall do the Job, something like:

`join s in db.CommunityPtsDocs on z.Id equals y.CommnunityPtId into k`, which will then further change your this statement
`from r in z` to `from r in k`. I am assuming that I have used the variables not used anywhere else to avoid confusion

Comment: this would most likely work, but I am getting an error on the "z.Id" it doesn't like "z"

Comment: Can you please update the models, for me to try, I am much well be versed with fluent syntax than SQL syntax

Comment: Check the modified version of code underneath, removed `z` and accessed `Id` using `y`, which of type `CommunityPts`, as that is getting joined with `CommunityPtsDocs`. 
Idea remains we fill result into a variable using `into` when we need to execute `from`, `Where` clause on `IEnumerable<T>`, as result of the previous statement

Comment: Also I am not sure whether `Id` belongs to `CertPoints` or `CommunityPts`, I have currently used `y.Id`, which means `CommunityPts`, but you may use `x.Id`, if its other way round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I feel I'm a navigation properties evangelist (fortunately, I'm not the only one).

The answer you accepted is OK, it does the job. But using any ORM like Entity Framework or LINQ-to-SQL you should avoid the `join` statement as much as possible. It's verbose and error-prone. It causes repetitive code and it's too easy to join the wrong properties erroneously.

You class `CertPoint` could have a 0..1-n navigation property `CommunityPts` (a list) and `CommunityPt` could have a 1-n navigation property `CommunityPtsDocs` (also a list). If you're using LINQ-to-SQL, chances are that they're already there but you're not aware of them. If you use Entity Framework code-first, you should add them yourself.

Having these navigation properties, your code is going to look like this:

```
from cert in CertPoints
from comm in cert.CommunityPts.DefaultIfEmpty()
from doc in comm.CommunityPtsDocs
where comm.CommunityId == id && cert.TypeId == 1 
select new Points
{
    pointId = cert.PointId,
    pointsDescription = cert.PointDescription,
    points = cert.Points,
    dateApplied = comm.DateApplied,
    pointsEarned = comm.PointsEarned,
    pointsPending = comm.Pending ? true : false,
    pointsApproved = comm.Approved ? true : false,
    notes = comm.Notes,
    something = doc.Something
})
```

Now the ORM will translate this into SQL with the correct joins and your code looks much cleaner (note that I also prefer more meaningful range variable names).

Comment: I have mostly worked with Linq 2 objects, not much with IQueryable, this surely provides lot of good information, where we allow provider like EF manage the entity relationship and create internal joins

Answer (score 1):

Following modification shall help in achieving the Task, though I prefer Fluent syntax, as that's much cleaner in my view to achieve the same, though I have not selected any column from `CommunityPtsDocs` in the Select statement

```
var regPoints = (from x in CertPoints
                 join y in CommunityPts on x.PointId equals y.PointId
                 join s in CommunityPtsDocs on y.Id equals s.CommnunityPtId into k
                 from t in (from r in k where r.CommunityId == id select r).DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where x.TypeId == 1 
                                 select new Points
                                 {
                                     pointId = x.PointId,
                                     pointsDescription = x.PointDescription,
                                     points = x.Points,
                                     dateApplied = t.DateApplied,
                                     pointsEarned = t.PointsEarned,
                                     pointsPending = t.Pending ? true : false,
                                     pointsApproved = t.Approved ? true : false,
                                     notes = t.Notes

                                 }).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am pretty new to LINQ so I am still experimenting. Thank you though, this does make great sense

Comment: That works except now the "communityPts" table is not accessable using the "t". I did find another way to this I think. It seems since I am using Entity Framework, I created an association between "communityPts" and communityPtsDoc by Id so "communityPtsDoc" is an ICollection in the CommunityPts Model.

Comment: Thank you again, you taught me some things, but ultimately have the files linked in Entity Framework was the solution. thank you again for taking the time

Comment: Glad it did help, my code snippet is more in line with Linq2Objects, surely there would be some difference with EF IQueryable approach